# Текст в кнопке "я рекомендую" от facebook

Tags: facebook, соцсети

Кнопку то на самом facebook сгенерировала, но как сделать, чтобы на странице в фейсбуке выводилась не только ссылка на сайт, но и его description и иконка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте на странице, которую лайкаете, дополнительные мета-теги. Например:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

В атрибутах content указываете либо описание, либо путь к картинке.

Comment: А есть подобное для twiter? ато, при генерации кнопки, можно либо задать текст либо указать, чтоб текст брался с заголовка страницы

Comment: а погуглить? [twitter follow button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button)